# How can I programmatically check out an item for edit in TFS using .NET Core?

Tags: c#, azure-devops, tfs, tfvc

Is there a way to check out a file, which is already mapped to a local workspace and downloaded, using [the new REST-based API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops)?

Previous answers mentioned using `TfsTeamProjectCollection` etc., but Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient and SOAP-based libraries [are not available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/soapsamples?view=azure-devops) for .NET Core as far as I understood.

Comment: I think you'll want TFS's older COM-based API, which is how programs worked with local workspaces for the past 15 years.

Comment: The Azure Pipelines Agent wraps the `tf.exe vc ...` commands by calling the executable. There is a Java based TEE version for that which works criss platform as well if you need that.

Comment: Check out the classes in this folder of their git repo for inspiration: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/tree/master/src%2FAgent.Plugins